# Make a string generated from my bash script to be ready to paste to elsewhere

Tags: bash, terminal, copy, paste, putty

I use putty to remotely connect to a linux server where I have a bash script(function) which I designed to generate some string. Normally I can just let my function to echo the string to the putty screen so that I can select the string using mouse and then directly paste to other place in Windows.

However I don't know if there is any way that I can make that string to be ready to paste to elsewhere without selecting it? To be more clear, in bash after I type in my function i can go out of putty and then crtl+c to paste the string generated by my function to Windows?

Thanks!

Comment: bash is not *aware* of how a client connecting via SSH achieves 'copy' and 'paste'. Any solution you devise has to be on the client (in this case, puTTY)

Answer (score 1):

If you run an X server on your client (PuTTY does support X forwarding for use in conjunction with such a tool, and several X servers for Windows are available -- including [a Cygwin port of Xorg](http://x.cygwin.com/)), you can use [XClip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xclip/) to directly interact with the remote clipboard, as such:

```
xclip -i <<<"$variable_with_things_to_copy"
```

Depending on the X server for Windows you're using, and how it manages integration with the native clipboard, it may be necessary to add `-selection primary`, `-selection secondary`, or `-selection clipboard` to specify which of the three clipboards X11 supports is tied to the native Windows one; experiment!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any non-commercial utilities for cross-platform clipboard sharing. Without a utility to synchronize your clipboards, you need to use the features of your PuTTY client.

The [PuTTY FAQ](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html) says:

> A.6.6 How do I copy and paste between PuTTY and other Windows
>   applications?
>
> Copy and paste works similarly to the X Window System. You use the
>   left mouse button to select text in the PuTTY window. The act of
>   selection automatically copies the text to the clipboard: there is no
>   need to press Ctrl-Ins or Ctrl-C or anything else. In fact, pressing
>   Ctrl-C will send a Ctrl-C character to the other end of your
>   connection (just like it does the rest of the time), which may have
>   unpleasant effects. The only thing you need to do, to copy text to the
>   clipboard, is to select it.

Another way of saying it is that PuTTY interacts with the *Windows* clipboard; it has no interaction at all with any clipboard facility on your remote host.